# Ionic 2 login popup using Modal and styling

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a projet where i want to use this type of login :

[image]

I have set up a modal correctly and i can dismiss it with no problem, but my problem is that it take the entire page, and i just want it to be as in the picture.

I don't know how to select all page in css file, already tried with * but it messing too much with what is inside the html file.

thank you in advance !

Edit :

code on the page that open the modal :

```
  showLogin() {
let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(LoginPage);
// this.navCtrl.push(modal);
modal.present();
}
```

code of the modal : 
HTML :

```
<ion-navbar class="modal-wrapper" *navbar>
  <ion-title>Sample Modal</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
<ion-content padding class="sample-modal-page">
  <p>my sample modal page<p>
     <ion-buttons start>
        <button (click)="dismiss()">
          Cancel
        </button>
      </ion-buttons>
</ion-content>
```

CSS :

```
page-login {
    .modal-wrapper {
        padding: 30px;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }
}
```

TS :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public viewCtrl: ViewController) {}

  dismiss(data) {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(data);
  }

}
```

My mistake is probably between html and css

Comment: remove `.modal-wrapper` and try

Comment: already tried, not working, i need a way to select everything on the page, or to use container (like div) but i don't know which one to use in ionic

Comment: Overlay is not added in background for me, What should i do? Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it finnaly, i was not selecting the right attribute.

Here what worked :

```
page-login {
    .sample-modal-page {
        padding: 30px;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }
}
```

Thank you to varun aaruru for helping me and all the caracteristic he gave for nice editing

here you can also find a nice post talking about how to nicely design it :
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/custom-modal-alert-with-html-form/47980/19

Comment: Thanks but where to we apply this? we use this one but it works for content only but we want for full screen

Answer (score 27):

My solution to this:

```
import { Renderer } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController, NavParams, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component(...)
class HomePage {

  constructor(
    public modalCtrl: ModalController
  ) { }

  presentProfileModal() {
    let profileModal = this.modalCtrl.create(Profile, { userId: 8675309 });
    profileModal.present();
  }

}

@Component(...)
class Profile {

  constructor(
    params: NavParams,
    public renderer: Renderer,
    public viewCtrl: ViewController
  ) {
    this.renderer.setElementClass(viewCtrl.pageRef().nativeElement, 'my-popup', true);
    console.log('UserId', params.get('userId'));
  }

}
```

Add this to your scss:

```
ion-modal.my-popup {
  @media (min-width: 300px) and (min-height: 500px) {
    ion-backdrop {
      visibility: visible;
    }
  }

  .modal-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 280px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 80vw;
    height: 50vh;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 16px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    background-color: #fafafa;
  }
}
```

Or this css, which will propose dynamic height:

```
ion-modal.my-popup {
  @media (min-height: 500px) {
    ion-backdrop {
      visibility: visible;
    }
  }

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: $z-index-overlay;

  display: flex;

  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  contain: strict;
  .modal-wrapper {
    &,
    .ion-page,
    .ion-page .content,
    .ion-page .content .scroll-content {
      contain: content;
      position: relative;
      top: auto;
      left: auto;
    }

    z-index: $z-index-overlay-wrapper;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;

    flex-direction: column;

    min-width: $alert-min-width;
    max-height: $alert-max-height;

    opacity: 0;

    height: auto;
    max-width: $alert-md-max-width;
    border-radius: $alert-md-border-radius;
    background-color: $alert-md-background-color;
    box-shadow: $alert-md-box-shadow;

    .ion-page .content {
      background-color: color($colors, light);
    }
  }
}
```

I just set a class to modal element when it is called and change the style.

- The modal implementation source is based in the official API [ModalController](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/modal/ModalController/#usage)

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing this, I'm have a list in modal, with this implementation I can't scroll the list. Any suggestion?

Comment: @AlanAlbuquerque 
 you can try it http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/scroll/Scroll/

Answer (score 0):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/varunaaruru/7zdvjfbL/)

> **its in ionic1 but css is same**

```
style="background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
position: absolute;
top: 80px;
left: 45px;
display: block;
width: 70%;
height: 62%;"
```

change values as needed

Comment: hello, my problem is not espacially what to write as attribute and style, but more what to select

Answer (score 0):

For Modal to show up in partial screen, you'll have to remove the ion-content tag and replace with a div. This is because ionic gets confused when there are two ion-content tags.

In this case there is one in the parent and one in the child modal. So its best to take it out of the child modal. Rest of the code remains same.