# Ionic 2 notification with pop ups (OneSignal)

Tags: cordova, push-notification, ionic2, popup, onesignal

I use `onesignal-cordova-plugin` and it work very well, but I want show pop up like telegram app when notification received!
example that what I want :

[image]

How can I do this? Is anyway for this?

Comment: You'd need to write a component that would look like the picture and use that as a popup template.

Comment: See thsi https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/custom-modal-alert-with-html-form/47980/30  and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42695169/ionic-2-login-popup-using-modal-and-styling

Comment: I want to show it out of app! when I create pop up it showed inside! @AnjilDhamala

Comment: @Ari , I don't have problem with modals or pop up! My problem is that I want to show these modal out of app as notification!

Comment: any update on this? did u get the answer @MohsenMd

Comment: @KishanOza Finally I create a answer for the question, you can use this now!

Comment: oh my god !!! Thanks :) @MohsenMd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I found a solution for this problem! We can set priority to high in one-signal dashboard when create a message, after push, we can see pop-up on device.

For more details see the [link](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK/issues/238).

Comment: sorry to i just tried with but couldn't get like whatsapp :(